# .NET Charting Custom label locations

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart, axis-labels

Is there a way to change the location of the axis label in .Net charts? I have the following graph: 
[image]

Right now, I have the label disabled, but what I want it to look like is this:

[image]

Is there a way to make it do this? I have custom labels that I would like to use overlaid on the graph.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A potential way of looking at this, from some research would be to set the YValue of the label such as:

```
<Points>               
  <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="1" YValues="14" />
  <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="2" YValues="14" />
  <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="3" YValues="14" />
<Points/>
```

Alternatively is this does not provide a solution you could try having a looking at [LabelStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489245.aspx).

I hope this helps!